# Insert Into with Select(PDO) and php

Tags: php, pdo

Ok so I need to insert some values into a table but i need to search for one of the data in the database so i tried to do it like this

```
$bookid = $_GET['var'];
$username = $_GET['username'];

$quer2 = "Insert Into reserved (username,bookid) VALUES ((SELECT userid FROM users WHERE   username=:username),:var)";
$query2 = $dbc->prepare($quer2);
$query2  ->bindParam(':username',$username);
$query2  ->bindParam(':var',$bookid);
$query2 ->execute();
```

The problem is that I get this error

> SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "username" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (6, null, 2014-09-22 13:06:33.262).

I tried the query in the database and it works so I guess that there is some error in bindParam but I can't understand what it is... So if anyone could help me I would appreciate it, thank you

Comment: there is a error here: $query2  ->bindParam(':var',$var); use $bookid instead of $var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
$query2  ->bindParam(':var',$var);
```

to

```
$query2  ->bindParam(':var',$bookid);
```

update your query to something like this

```
Insert Into reserved (username,bookid)
SELECT userid, :var FROM users WHERE username=:username
```

just bind the params and run the query.

Comment: thx and sorry but that was a stupid mistake and the problems still remains ony it is for 'username' now... i'll  re edit the code

Comment: @Alex I have updated my answer, you can check it now.